# (Py2neo) - How to return relationship id from neo4j database by using py2neo instruction

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

Are there any py2neo instructions to return id of relationship edge that is stored in neo4j database?
Thank you.

This is how it looks like in cypher:

```
match (a:SINGLE_NODE)-[r:IS_CONNECTED]->(b:SINGLE_NODE) 
where a.name='KEY' and b.name = 'ROOM' return id(r)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but may I ask why you want to retriede the ID of the relation ? It's strongly discouraged to use them as an ID may be reused later when the relation has been dropped.

Comment: @Muldec thank you for response, i want the id because i want it to set relationship entity ref by id.

Comment: What do you mean by "set relationship entity ref by id" ? Using the ID as a property value ?

Comment: yes, actually i want to update relationship property value after this condition  "relmatcher.match(nodes=(n1, n2), r_type="IS_CONNECTED")"

Comment: Is there anyhow to update relationship property value without using cypher

Answer (score 1):

This solution works prety well for me :

```
for rel in db.match((a,None), r_type=None):
    print(rel.end_node["name"], rel.start_node["name"], rel.identity)
```